Troubleshooting MPI4py Error When Using Numba-Accelerated Python Code
I'm attempting to accelerate a piece of Python code using Numba. Within this code, I'm also employing mpi4py for parallelization. However, I've encountered an error. I've attempted to provide a minimal error-reproducing example below:
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
from mpi4py import MPI

#####MPI setting#####
comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.Get_rank()
size=comm.Get_size()
N_theta_to_scan=1000
n_per_proc=int(N_theta_to_scan/size)
n_more=int(N_theta_to_scan%size)
if rank<n_more:
    start=rank*(n_per_proc+1)
    number_to_cal=n_per_proc+1
else:
    start=n_more*(n_per_proc+1)+(rank-n_more)*n_per_proc
    number_to_cal=n_per_proc

#####function#####
@njit(parallel=True)
def func1(na,nb,nc):
    to_sum=np.zeros(na*nb*nc)
    for a in prange(0,na):
        for b in prange(0,nb):
            for c in prange(0,nc):
                to_sum[a*nb*nc+b*nc+c]=a*b*c
    out=np.sum(to_sum)
    return out

@njit(parallel=True)
def func2(start,number_to_cal):
    to_sum=np.zeros(number_to_cal)
    for i in prange(start,start+number_to_cal):
        to_sum[i-start]=func1(i,i*i,i*i*i)
    out2=np.sum(to_sum)
    return out2

#####main section#####
to_be_gather=np.array([func2(start,number_to_cal)])
gatheres=np.zeros(0)
comm.Reduce(to_be_gather,gatheres,op=MPI.SUM)

The error occurs for this segment of the code:
MemoryError: Allocation failed (probably too large).

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/workspace/wuliang/hanlin/test/test.py", line 38, in <module>
    to_be_gather=func2(start,number_to_cal)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SystemError: CPUDispatcher(<function func2 at 0x2aed19d7b420>) returned a result with an exception set

Next, I attempted to remove func1() and modified func2() by replacing to_sum[i-start]=func1(i,i*i,i*i*i) with to_sum[i-start]=i, which resulted in successful execution. Additionally, I tried running the code with only rank 0 executing the main function, i.e., running the code under the condition if rank==0:, which also ran successfully. I'm wondering where the error lies, and what modifications should I make to achieve the functionality of the current code?

are you sure mpi4py is needed to trigger the error?

@GillesGouaillardet Thank you for your response. I tried it out and it seems that the issue might not be with mpi4py or even with numba. I removed mpi4py and numba, and there was no error. However, when I added an extra loop in func1(), I encountered an error stating that there wasn't enough memory to allocate for the to_sum array. Perhaps this is the reason for the error, and mpi4py simply amplified this issue, leading me to mistakenly believe that the problem originated there.

@GillesGouaillardet However, this raises another question: If I indeed want to store data computed within a loop, totaling nanbncnd... items (in short, a large amount of data), how should I proceed?

Note that MPI and Numba does not mix well in term of performance unless you only have few processes. Indeed, the Numba code will be compiled separately in each process. Compiling parallel functions can be quite expensive. Anyway it seems you do not have enough memory here mainly due to the actual code.

In reference to the code of original question and to comments regarding coupling Numba and MPI; using MPI from within Numba compiled code (also with parallel=True) is possible with the numba-mpi package.
Here's a compute-pi-in-parallel example from the package README where a reduction is performed within @numba.jit decorated function (using mpi4py, the reduction needs to be done outside of the JIT-compiled code, as in the question):
import numba, numpy as np, numba_mpi

N_TIMES = 10000

@numba.jit
def get_pi_part(n_intervals=1000000, rank=0, size=1):
    h = 1 / n_intervals
    partial_sum = 0.0
    for i in range(rank + 1, n_intervals, size):
        x = h * (i - 0.5)
        partial_sum += 4 / (1 + x**2)
    return h * partial_sum

@numba.jit
def pi_numba_mpi(n_intervals):
    pi = np.array([0.])
    part = np.empty_like(pi)
    for _ in range(N_TIMES):
        part[0] = get_pi_part(n_intervals, numba_mpi.rank(), numba_mpi.size())
        numba_mpi.allreduce(part, pi, numba_mpi.Operator.SUM)

The package README includes a performance comparison with mpi4py.
